# Change SQL Server datetime/date format to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to change display format of all dates/datetimes among entire instance/database (whichever is possible). 
I tried changing default language for the instance and for single users and it doesn't work. It always displays YYYY-MM-DD. Can this be changed without messing with the code to always include FORMAT function?

Comment: There is no date format. It's a binary value. There are hundreds of duplicates that explain this. Please don't "but I can see". Search for the duplicates

Comment: there is no datetime/date format in the database. Dates are stored as numerical values. The format you see them in your client must be set in the client you are using

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function and write the format you want

```
SELECT FORMAT(GetDate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```